# How to select a css class as selected dynamically in mvc

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm working on mvc4 project.
I have following `html code` which is of `menu items`
when we clicked on new menu it will take `css class active automatically`

```
    <div class="span3">
        <!-- Filter -->
        <nav id="options" class="work-nav">
            <ul id="filters" class="option-set" data-option-key="filter">
                <li><a href="#filter" data-option-value="*" class="selected">.Net</a></li>
                <li><a href="#filter" data-option-value=".javaset">Java</a></li>
                <li><a href="#filter" data-option-value=".rubyset">Ruby</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <!-- End Filter -->
```

I want to convert this into `Mvc4 view cshtml` All Type are coming from database so i have used `foreach` but how do I apply class `class="selected"` which is currently active menu?

I tried something like

```
foreach(item in Model)
{
 <div class="row">
        <div class="span3">
            <!-- Filter -->
            <nav id="options" class="work-nav">
                <ul id="filters" class="option-set" data-option-key="filter">
                    <li><a href="#filter" data-option-value="*" class="selected">@item.TypeName</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <!-- End Filter -->
        </div>
}
```

guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>I suppose that there's some condition on the `item` that allows you to determine if it is the currently active one. And then you could use the conditional operator like that:</strike>

```
@{
    var selected = item.IsCurrentItem ? " class=\"selected\"" : "";
}
<li><a href="#filter" data-option-value="*"@Html.Raw(selected)>@item.TypeName</a></li>
```

This example assumes that your model has an `IsCurrentItem` boolean property. If it doesn't you should replace it with the corresponding condition that will determine if it is the current item.

---

UPDATE:

It appears that you are attempting to toggle the selected class on the current item when this item is clicked. You could use javascript for that.

For example:

```
$(function() {
    $('.work-nav a').click(function() {
        // remove the selected class from all anchors
        $('.row a').removeClass('selected');

        // Add the selected class to the currently clicked anchor
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    });
});
```

Also note that you have produced broken markup. You have used `<nav id="options"` and `<ul id="filters"` inside a foreach loop. This means that potentially you might have more than one element with the same id in your HTML page. This results in invalid HTML! In HTML all ids must be **unique**.

---

UPDATE 2:

In order to make the first item selected initially when the page loads you could use the following:

```
foreach(var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span3">
            <!-- Filter -->
            <nav class="work-nav">
                <ul class="option-set" data-option-key="filter">
                    <li>
                        @{
                            var item = Model[i];
                            var selected = i == 0 ? " class=\"selected\"" : "";
                        }
                        <a href="#filter" data-option-value="*"@Html.Raw(selected)>@item.TypeName</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <!-- End Filter -->
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Some condition means in plain html we do not have any condition its working only depending upon css class.
When `I click on next menu it will automatically take as Selected css class`

Comment: Ohhh, then you should use javascript, not server side. I will update my answer.

Comment: I have updated my answer with an example of how to achieve that with jquery.

Comment: great should i need to use this code now?
`@{
    var selected = item.IsCurrentItem ? " class=\"selected\"" : "";
}
<li><a href="#filter" data-option-value="*"@Html.Raw(selected)>@item.TypeName</a></li>`

Comment: No, absolutely not. You could use that when the page is loaded, to initially determine the selected item if you want. For example if you are persisting this selection somewhere on the server this could be useful. If not, I suppose that you will just pick the first item to be selected. Once the page is loaded, you will act upon it with javascript.

Comment: But need to write foreach to get all menu names ? I mean you said about broken html thats why asked you

Comment: Remove the `id="..."` attribute. Or prefix them with some indexer variable. What I am saying is that you cannot have 2 elements with the same id which is exactly what you will end up if you hardcode your ids in a foreach loop.

Comment: its working fine but very first time all are selected as we given class :( can we make 1st menu selected at first time?

Comment: Yes, you can make it selected initially. You have 2 possibilities: either do it on the server (preferred) or use javascript.

Comment: need to find out 1st element hmm any clue though I will find it :) thanks

Comment: Use a `for` loop instead of a `foreach`. This will allow you to keep track of the index. I have updated my answer to provide an example.

Comment: thanks a lot if your are interested please be a part of our technical website www.careertechz.com

Comment: You are welcome. Thanks for the invitation but I am not interested.

Answer (score 1):

Have your viewmodel a property to store the selected item name/id.

```
public class PageViewModel
{
  public int SelectedMenuID { set;get;}
  //Now your existing viewmodel properties goes here
  public List<MenuItem> MenuItems { set;get;}
}
```

in your action method, set the `SelectedMenuID` property value.

```
public ActionResult Customers()
{
  var vm=new PageViewModel();
  vm.SelectedMenuID=5; // hardcoded for demo. 
  vm.MenuItems=LoadMenuItemsCollectionFromSomeWhere();
  return View(vm);
}
```

now in your view you can check it the SelectedMenuID is same as the current item's ID in the loop.

```
@model PageViewModel
@forach(var menu in Model.MenuItems)
{
  <div>
    <a href="#filter" class="@(Model.SelectedMenuID==menu.MenuID?"selected":"")">
      @menu.Name
    </a>
  </div>

}
```

Assuming `MenuItem` class has 2 properties, `MenuID` and `MenuName`