# How to return multiple model object from one Index controller method in mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have controller.cs code :

```
public class GroupsController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            GroupTypeRepository groupTypeRepo = new GroupTypeRepository();

            var groupTypeNames = groupTypeRepo.GetAll().ToList();

    //like GroupType I have Group also so i want to pass both GroupType and Group object to my below return View("Groups", groupTypeNames);
        // how can i do this?

            return View("Groups", groupTypeNames);
        }
```

I tried it in doing in `/Model Folder in Model.cs` but its not good approach please guide how to achieve this?
thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't return multiple models from a controller action. What you do instead is define a view model that will contain all the necessary information and then return this view model.

For example:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public List<string> GroupTypeNames { get; set; }
    public string SomeOtherProperty { get; set; }
}
```

and then:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
     GroupTypeRepository groupTypeRepo = new GroupTypeRepository();

     var model = new MyViewModel();
     model.GroupTypeNames = groupTypeRepo.GetAll().ToList();
     model.SomeOtherProperty = "some other property value";

     return View("Groups", model);
}
```

Now of course your view should be typed to the view model:

```
@model MyViewModel
```

and if you wanted to access the some property:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.GroupTypeNames)
{
    <div>@item</div>
}
```

or:

```
@model.SomeOtherProperty
```

Comment: superb info can you please give me threads any link sorry to bother again as i'm new bie :(

Comment: I don't understand what threads and links you are asking for. That's basic stuff. You should read the getting started tutorials at http://asp.net/mvc

Comment: what if `SomeOtherProperty ` is also like `GroupTypeNames ` i mean `List` i just need to take same as in viewmodel is it :)

Comment: Erm what? Sorry I don't understand what you are asking. You could have arbitrary complex properties in your view model.

Comment: hey related with previous question i used above code to return two model object but now getting error for previuos code for loop 
 `Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'method group'`
question was http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20827155/how-to-select-a-css-class-as-selected-dynamically-in-mvc

Comment: C'mon, that's basic C#. You have a class called `MyViewModel` with a property called `GroupTypeNames` that is a `List<string>`. So the correct way to write a loop is: `for (var i = 0; i < Model.GroupTypeNames.Count; i++) { var item = Model.GroupTypeNames[i]; .... }`. Really, I would recommend you learn C# first before getting into ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44105/discussion-between-ashuthinks-and-darin-dimitrov)

Comment: On which line did you get the error? Did you update your `@model` directive to `@model MyViewModel`?

Comment: Cheers. Now please read the getting started tutorials for ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 1):

Using PartialResult You can divide your complex code into multiple Partials. For example here is the code.

```
 public class Type1
    {
        public struct Test
        {

        }
    }

    public class Type2
    {
    }
```

and this is my code that I used in partial

```
@using MVC5.Models

@model  List<Type1.Test>
```

in another partial you can call type2.

Now make a action in Controller like this

```
   public PartialViewResult Partial1()
        {
            ViewData.Model = new List<Type1.Test>();
            return PartialView();
        }
```

Now in my index.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

@{
    Html.Action("Partial1","Home");   
}
```

I have called the partial1 in my index ActionResult. Using this implementation you can use model in every partialresult you have.

As darin say Make a call that hold all these sub-data and pass them from controller to Models.

I want to suggest you to pass multiple data on Views through ViewData or ViewBag (ViewBag is dynamic). See this post http://www.rachelappel.com/when-to-use-viewbag-viewdata-or-tempdata-in-asp.net-mvc-3-applications